# Unable to call component method. Public method [previousPageUrl] not found on component

Tags: laravel

I have a custom paginator view, followed this doc https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/pagination. But it gives me `Unable to call component method. Public method [previousPageUrl] not found on component.` error when clicking the pagination.

- custom.blade.php

```php
<div>
    @if ($paginator->hasPages())
        <nav role="navigation" aria-label="{{ __('Pagination Navigation') }}"
             class="tw-flex tw-items-center tw-justify-between">
            <div class="tw-flex tw-justify-between tw-flex-1 sm:tw-hidden">
                @if ($paginator->onFirstPage())
                    <span
                        class="tw-relative tw-inline-flex tw-items-center tw-px-4 tw-py-2 tw-text-sm tw-font-medium tw-text-gray-500 tw-bg-white tw-border tw-border-gray-300 tw-cursor-default tw-leading-5 tw-rounded-md">
                    {!! __('pagination.previous') !!}
                </span>
                @else
                    <button wire:click="previousPageUrl"
                       class="tw-relative tw-inline-flex tw-items-center tw-px-4 tw-py-2 tw-text-sm tw-font-medium tw-text-gray-700 tw-bg-white tw-border tw-border-gray-300 tw-leading-5 tw-rounded-md hover:tw-text-gray-500 focus:tw-outline-none focus:tw-ring tw-ring-gray-300 focus:tw-border-blue-300 active:tw-bg-gray-100 active:tw-text-gray-700 tw-transition tw-ease-in-out tw-duration-150">
                        {!! __('pagination.previous') !!}
                    </button>
                @endif

                @if ($paginator->hasMorePages())
                    <button wire:click="nextPageUrl"
                       class="tw-relative tw-inline-flex tw-items-center tw-px-4 tw-py-2 tw-text-sm tw-font-medium tw-text-gray-700 tw-bg-white tw-border tw-border-gray-300 tw-leading-5 tw-rounded-md hover:tw-text-gray-500 focus:tw-outline-none focus:tw-ring tw-ring-gray-300 focus:tw-border-blue-300 active:tw-bg-gray-100 active:tw-text-gray-700 tw-transition tw-ease-in-out tw-duration-150">
                        {!! __('pagination.next') !!}
                    </button>
                @else
                    <span
                        class="tw-relative tw-inline-flex tw-items-center tw-px-4 tw-py-2 tw-text-sm tw-font-medium tw-text-gray-500 tw-bg-white tw-border tw-border-gray-300 tw-cursor-default tw-leading-5 tw-rounded-md">
                    {!! __('pagination.next') !!}
                </span>
                @endif
            </div>

...
```

- ActivityLogsTable .php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Table\Tenant\Activitylogs;

use App\Models\Tenant\ActivityLog;
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithPagination;

class ActivityLogsTable extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;

...
```

Comment: can you add your `render` method as well in question?

Comment: Try change it to `previousPage` instead of `previousPageURL` as per the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's the livewire example of how paginator works, not precisely how you must use it. Normally you define the paginator collection instance and bind it to the blade component

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Table\Tenant\Activitylogs;

use App\Models\Tenant\ActivityLog;
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithPagination;

class ActivityLogsTable extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;
    protected $paginationTheme = 'bootstrap';

    public $collection;

    public function render()
    {
        $this->collection = Model::paginate(10);
        return view('component-blade');
    }
}
```

and in the blade

```
<div>
  @foreach($collection as $item)
    {{ $item->name }}
  @endforeach
  {{ $collection->links() }}
</div>
```

[image]